# How to show specific product on cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

How do i show one specific product in the cart page for promotion and want that product be able to add to the cart?

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

From the merch docs:

> Cross-sells
>
> Cross-sell products are similar to impulse purchases positioned next
>   to the cash register in the checkout line of a grocery store. Products
>   offered as a cross-sell appear on the shopping cart page, just before
>   the customer begins the checkout process.

If you specify a product as a cross sell item on any item, when that item is added to the cart the list of applicable cross-sells will appear.

By default in Magento the list of cross sells in the base template and RWD templates include the ability to add to cart.

---

<sub>Source:</sub>

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee_docs/content/catalog/product-relationships-cross-sells.html